# Parent mousenter/mouseleave event fired only on children

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouseenter, mouseleave

Consider the following fiddle: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tRP2k/)

How can I get the events fired from parent `div` (class `outer`) not from its children?

Comment: Post your code here instead of just on another site. After 22 months, 30 questions and 5 answers, I'd think you'd know this.

Comment: In non-IE browsers, you *can't* actually prevent the event from firing on the children. jQuery provides a fix so that your handler is only invoked on the outermost element, even though the event does occur. The trouble with your demo is that there's no padding/margin between outer and inner, so the `e.target` will be the inner. I don't know why jQuery doesn't fix the `e.target` in this situation. Seems like a bug.

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct behavior: you caught the event on a parent `div`, but the actual sender of event, that is the element who triggered it, was the inner `div` (probably that's because there is not space between parent & inner divs like @squint said). That's what `e.target` is used for. `this` property in context of the event handler always gets you the element that handles the event.

```
$('.outer').on('mouseenter',function(e){alert($(this).attr('class'));});
```

JSFIddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tRP2k/3/

Read this for details & examples: http://api.jquery.com/event.target/